set state function in the custom_dialog doesn't work
setState function in the custom_dialog page dosen't work
in this code, I want to show a list of customers with a specific data for each customer. The issue is when I want to add a new customer through the floating action button that's showing dialog1 from the custom_dialog page, the customer is added to the list but does not appear in in the page
main page code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/custom_dialog.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/customers.dart';

List<Customers> customersList = [
  Customers(
    name: 'munsef',
    itemName: 'mobile',
    price: 100,
    profit: 30,
    period: 12,
    key: UniqueKey(),
  ),
];

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Dialog1();
                    });
              }),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('List of Items'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: customersList.length,
              itemBuilder: (element, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  child: Card(
                    child: customersList[index],
                  ),
                  onLongPress: () {
                    customersList.removeAt(index);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  
                );
              })),
    );
     }
     }

custome_dialog page:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/customers.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/main.dart';

class Dialog1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Dialog1({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return dialog1State();
  }
}

class dialog1State extends State<Dialog1> {
  final TextEditingController customerNamecontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController itemNamecontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController pricecontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController profitcontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController periodcontr = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Add customer'),
      content: Form(
          child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text("Customer's name:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: customerNamecontr,
          ),
          Text("Item's name:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: itemNamecontr,
          ),
          Text("Price:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: pricecontr,
          ),
          Text("Profit:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: profitcontr,
          ),
          Text("Period:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: periodcontr,
          ),
        ],
      )),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              double? price = double.tryParse(pricecontr.text);
              int? profit = int.tryParse(profitcontr.text);
              int? period = int.tryParse(periodcontr.text);
              customersList.add(Customers(
                name: customerNamecontr.text,
                itemName: itemNamecontr.text,
                price: price!,
                profit: profit!,
                period: period!,
                key: UniqueKey(),
              ));
              setState(() {});
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('Add'))
      ],
    );
  }
}


It looks like you have a classic master/detail pattern.  A setState in the detail screen will have no impact on the master screen.  Specifically, "setState .. pop" would be useless.  You'll probably need to shift to Riverpod, and have both screens observe a common state.

You are calling set state in the context of the dialog what you need to do is to call the set state in the context of the list view , modify your dialog to
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/customers.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/main.dart';

class Dialog1 extends StatefulWidget {
    Dialog1({super.key, required this.refresh});
    final Function refresh;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return dialog1State();
  }
}

class dialog1State extends State<Dialog1> {
  final TextEditingController customerNamecontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController itemNamecontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController pricecontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController profitcontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController periodcontr = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Add customer'),
      content: Form(
          child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text("Customer's name:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: customerNamecontr,
          ),
          Text("Item's name:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: itemNamecontr,
          ),
          Text("Price:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: pricecontr,
          ),
          Text("Profit:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: profitcontr,
          ),
          Text("Period:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: periodcontr,
          ),
        ],
      )),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              double? price = double.tryParse(pricecontr.text);
              int? profit = int.tryParse(profitcontr.text);
              int? period = int.tryParse(periodcontr.text);
              customersList.add(Customers(
                name: customerNamecontr.text,
                itemName: itemNamecontr.text,
                price: price!,
                profit: profit!,
                period: period!,
                key: UniqueKey(),
              ));
              widget.refresh();
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('Add'))
      ],
    );
  }
}

and modify your main to
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/custom_dialog.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/customers.dart';

List<Customers> customersList = [
  Customers(
    name: 'munsef',
    itemName: 'mobile',
    price: 100,
    profit: 30,
    period: 12,
    key: UniqueKey(),
  ),
];

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Dialog1(refresh: () {
                    setState(() {});
                  });
                    });
              }),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('List of Items'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: customersList.length,
              itemBuilder: (element, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  child: Card(
                    child: customersList[index],
                  ),
                  onLongPress: () {
                    customersList.removeAt(index);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  
                );
              })),
    );
     }
     }

this will cause your child dialog to call the set state in ths context of its parent

sorry, but this didn't work. Do you have any other solutions or suggestions?

Are you sure you did it right? Because it worked for me , make sure to call the widget.refresh() as a function not as a result (with brackets) , if you edited your code maybe you forgot some changes try copying and pasting it

oops, yes this is the issue, I forgot the brackets.  Thank you so much it's worked now

You have to create a function to add new customer in MyAppState class and pass that to Dialog1
Example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import 'package:untitled66/custom_dialog.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/customers.dart';

List<Customers> customersList = [
  Customers(
    name: 'munsef',
    itemName: 'mobile',
    price: 100,
    profit: 30,
    period: 12,
    key: UniqueKey(),
  ),
];

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
void addNewCustomer(Customers newCustomer){
      customersList.add(newCustomer);
      setState({});
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Dialog1(onTap:addNewCustomer);
                    });
              }),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('List of Items'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: customersList.length,
              itemBuilder: (element, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  child: Card(
                    child: customersList[index],
                  ),
                  onLongPress: () {
                    customersList.removeAt(index);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  
                );
              })),
    );
     }
     }

And change your Dialog1 Widget to
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/customers.dart';
import 'package:untitled66/main.dart';

class Dialog1 extends StatefulWidget {
    Dialog1({super.key, required this.onTap});
    final Function(Customers newCustomer) onTap;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return dialog1State();
  }
}

class dialog1State extends State<Dialog1> {
  final TextEditingController customerNamecontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController itemNamecontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController pricecontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController profitcontr = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController periodcontr = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Add customer'),
      content: Form(
          child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text("Customer's name:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: customerNamecontr,
          ),
          Text("Item's name:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: itemNamecontr,
          ),
          Text("Price:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: pricecontr,
          ),
          Text("Profit:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: profitcontr,
          ),
          Text("Period:"),
          TextFormField(
            controller: periodcontr,
          ),
        ],
      )),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              double? price = double.tryParse(pricecontr.text);
              int? profit = int.tryParse(profitcontr.text);
              int? period = int.tryParse(periodcontr.text);
              onTap(Customers(name: ........)) // Add the customer here
            
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('Add'))
      ],
    );
  }

 }

I am too bad at this, but i hope you understood .

You have to call "widget.onTap" ...
